# Permutations without but also kinda with repitition

Tags: python

I'm very new to coding but I was needing some help. My problem is if I have the code:

```
import itertools
result = itertools.permutations('ABCD',4)
for i in result:
  print(i)
```

This got me all 24 permutations but how would I code the same thing but if the letters were A  B, B and C for example as if you swap the Bs around, it makes no difference?

I'd appreciate any help I can get, thank you.

Comment: Could you rephrase the question please? And could you show us an example of what you're looking for?

Comment: `for i in set(result)` ?

Comment: Just do `result = set(result)`

Comment: Marcust, were you looking for combinations or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just turn it to a `set` and it will remove the duplicates. If that is what you are asking.

```
import itertools
result = itertools.permutations('ABBD',4)
result = set(result)
for i in result:
  print(i)
```

Comment: This is a bad example. There are no duplicates in `permutations('ABCD', 4)`

Comment: Typo. Meant to do ABBD

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're referring to [combinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination).

Just use `itertools.combinations()`

Comment: This might be the answer, but some commenters think he just wants to remove duplicates. We should probably get clarification of the question.

Comment: Yeah, the question is a bit unclear. If he's just asking how to remove duplicates, then obviously `set`'s are the way to go

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is to generate permutations and use `set` over them.

```
result = itertools.permutations('ABBC',4)
>>> b = set(result)
>>> len(b)
12
```